# PHP bin2hex vulnerable to timing attack?

Tags: php, csrf, timing-attack

I've read in a few places[1][2][3] of the desire to make PHP's bin2hex constant time.

**In what scenarios would bin2hex be vulnerable to a timing attack?**

**Is this below code for handling a CSRF token vulnerable to a timing attack?**

```
// generate a CSRF token, n is some large number
$token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(n));
// ... store $token on in the PHP session and render form with CSRF token
// ... on form submission compare the form's CSRF token to the session token
hash_equals($sessionToken, $formToken);
```

1. http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/11/its-all-about-time.html
2. https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/909
3. http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-internals/14bs5tmqbr/php-src-constant-time-bin2hex-implementation-909

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### In what scenarios would bin2hex be vulnerable to a timing attack?

The timing attack discussed in the mailing list and blog post is a cache-timing attack, which was famously demonstrated by Daniel J. Bernstein against OpenSSL's implementation of AES [here](http://cr.yp.to/antiforgery/cachetiming-20050414.pdf) (PDF).

In order for `bin2hex()` to be vulnerable to a timing attack, the following conditions must be met:

1. Internally, it either indexes or branches based on the secret we are trying to protect (e.g. HMAC key). The PHP implementation [**does** index based on what could potentially be a secret](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/257054e81d4dad73bf9d09cd206d3a6727ad1777/ext/standard/string.c#L138-L139).
2. The attacker has to be able to alter the state of the processor cache somehow. (e.g. Renting a neighbor VM on the same baremetal machine with your cloud provider and executing a strategy similar to [FLUSH+RELOAD](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/448.pdf).)
3. The attacker can rapidly issue many valid requests from a privileged network position with minimal network jitter (surprisingly trivial these days).
4. The key we want to protect is reused. (General case; some CSRF tokens are not reused.)

The feasibility of such an attack is still an unknown, but [patching this potential side-channel](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/blob/90bb7de6ba04581c5bbc704adfa6d8e6309d6583/src/Crypto.php#L674-L729) is actually not that difficult. The previously linked methods were derived from [libsodium's bin2hex implementation](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/blob/a8e411585167f1e794e3eddadb19aef93907df80/src/libsodium/sodium/utils.c#L99-L180), which was provided by [CodesInChaos](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/180/codesinchaos).

#### Is this below code for handling a CSRF token vulnerable to a timing attack?

I don't know. The `bin2hex()` might be a very minor concern, but not one that I can demonstrate a practical exploit for. Maybe someone in [Crypto Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) can?

#### Update: There's a Lib for That

If you use [paragonie/constant_time_encoding](https://github.com/paragonie/constant_time_encoding) (which didn't exist when you asked this question), you shouldn't leak any information via cache timing.

```
<?php
use \ParagonIE\ConstantTime\Hex;

$rawBinary = random_bytes(32);
$data = Hex::encode($rawBinary);
$decoded = Hex::decode($data);
```

This library cover all of the RFC 4648 encoding schemes:

- Hex
- Base32
- Base32Hex
- Base64
- Base64UrlSafe
- Base64DotSlash
- Base64DotSlashOrdered

The latter two are compatible with `crypt(3)`.

Comment: You should add Libsodium's [constant time bin2hex/hex2bin](https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/content/helpers/#hexadecimal-encodingdecoding) algorithms.

Comment: Ah just saw you already mentioned it. A bit hidden though.